# Slow Internet while proxy server is enabled

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, windows-10

So, when I first turn on my work laptop and attempt to browse the intranet the page hangs for 30 seconds to a minute before loading the page. When browsing the internet to something like Google.co.uk or google search of pages i know aren't cached. It seems to take a few minutes to load the page.

However the connection it's self is fast.. If I browser to one of our network shares and copy a 2GB files it's super fast.

If i run a registry file which contains the following settings

Then head over to Internet explorer>Settings>Connection>Lan Settings.. Turn off Proxy server.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel]
"Proxy"=dword:00000000

"ConnectionsTab"=dword:00000000

"AdvancedTab"=dword:00000000

"Connection Settings"=dword:00000000

"Connwiz Admin Lock"=dword:00000000
```

or Run a batch with the following:

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults
```

The internet then works extremely quick at browsing internal and external sites.

This issue doesn't appear to be a problem on similar laptop with the same grouyp policies applied.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this article](https://itstillworks.com/proxy-setting-making-internet-slow-21505.html):

*When you browse the Web without a proxy, your computer communicates directly with each website you visit. Using a proxy turns this one-step process into a three-step one. Instead of your computer communicating directly with a website, it communicates with the proxy server, which in turn communicates with the website, and finally it shares the website's information with you. More steps means more time, so, all else being equal, using a proxy will always slow down your browsing speeds. It's just a question of how much, and that varies depending on the proxy server you use.*

Comment: If i take my colleagues Laptop identical in permissions, model, OU and security groups. 

My laptop takes 2-3 minutes to load a page including site we host internally which shouldn't use the proxy. My colleagues is 20 seconds.

Comment: Try to use [F12 developer tools Network  tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v%3dvs.85)) to analyze the traffic spend time.